# Soap SSL handshake

Tags: java, security, soap, ssl

My client is successfully getting response from server through HTTP.

```
SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();

SOAPMessage soapMessageResponse = connection.call(soapRequest, new URL(serviceLocation));
```

I want SSL communication between client/server.

In another project I am successfully creating `SSLSocketFactory` from a `KeyStore` and `TrustManagerFactory` for **SSL** handshake.

How can I use `SSLSocketFactory` code in webservice client to make client **SSL** communication successful to call server.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This line of code will not work in case of SSL.

```
SOAPMessage soapMessageResponse = connection.call(soapRequest, new URL(serviceLocation));
```

Create trustmanager and keymanagers from [here](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=855).

In order to get response through SSL from axis2 webservice you need to open streams like given [here](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=853)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it will use the default SSLContext. You can change that with SSLContext.setDefault().

```
SSLContext c = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
tmf.init(yourKeystore);
TrustManager tm = tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
tm.
c.init(null, tm, null);
```

Here are some [other values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#TrustManagerFactory) for the string parameters above.

If you need more complete control, you can implement your own subclass of SSLContext which returns your own implementation of SSLSocketFactory and set that SSLContext as the default:

```
public class MySSLContext extends SSLContext {

    private SSLContext wrapped;
    private SSLSocketFactory mySocketFactory;

    public MySSLContext(SSLContext toWrap, SSLSocketFactory mySocketFactory) {
        wrapped = toWrap;
        this.mySocketFactory = mySocketFactory;
    }

    public SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {
        return mySocketFactory;
    }

    public SSLSessionContext getClientSessionContext() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    // other delegates

}
```

Comment: Incidentally, I hate APIs like this that only let you have one instance of something active at a time per VM. Pretty much the only acceptable use of static in an API are factory methods and constants.

Comment: you said:"pretty sure it will use the default SSLContext". Where I can use SSLContext? Can you brief it please.

Comment: I am doing so. But where to use this SSLContext in SOAP client code? As I discussed in question that i am building SSLSocketFactory from SSLContext.

Comment: As I said, I think whatever you set on SSLContext.setDefault() is what SOAPConnectionFactory will use. If you want that SSLContext to use your SSLSocketFactory, you need to subclass SSLContext. The delegate implementation I suggested above should work.

Comment: you are missing SOAPConnection class. How can SOAPConnection know that trust has been established?

Comment: That is the point of my first comment. It is a bad API design. Java's implementation of SOAPConnection is HttpSOAPConnection. HttpSOAPConnection calls URL.openConnection. URL.openConnection uses the value provided on URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory. This is set to HttpsURLConnectionImpl, which calls HttpsURLConnection, which calls SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(). It's a huge chain of mostly static methods. You can only modify it globally. In theory, you could unwind that whole mess and set your own URLStreamHandlerFactory. Trust me, you don't want to do that unless you absolutely must.

Comment: This is really going to be a mess. As I can create SSLSocketFactory. Please guide me with an example code after creating this factory.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any more to add. The code I have provided above shows what I propose doing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  if you add this code your webservice class ı think your problem will be solve .

```
     `

   //just put it your somewhere 
 public static class miTM implements javax.net.ssl.TrustManager,
    javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return null;
}

public boolean isServerTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
    return true;
}

public boolean isClientTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
    return true;
}

public void checkServerTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
    return;
}

public void checkClientTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
    return;
}
    }





 // CAll This function in your webservice class .
private static void trustAllHttpsCertificates() throws Exception {

// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains:

javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] trustAllCerts =

new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[1];

javax.net.ssl.TrustManager tm = new miTM();

trustAllCerts[0] = tm;

javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sc =

javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);

javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(

sc.getSocketFactory());

    }
```

Comment: This will mean the webservice trusts all SSL certificates without checking them, which probably isn't a good idea in a production service.